# Django - how to set up a project with sub-projects (sort of)

Tags: django

I am building a new Django project. For example sake, lets say that it's for managing multiple car dealerships. Perhaps a parent company owns 5-10 distinct dealerships, with each dealership being in a different city with its own staff and its own inventory.

I'm trying to figure out how best to create the Django project to handle this structure. I want a high level view where management can view all dealerships and their aggregate data, but then can drill down and manage each specific dealership and all its data. So something like this:

- Main project is for managing car dealerships
- Main project needs to have some high level data such as:

  - Overview of all dealerships
  - Overview of financial data (which is the aggregate of all individual dealership financials)
  - Ability to add new dealerships

But then each *dealership* needs the following info, which is all specific to *that* dealership:

- Staff of dealership
- Inventory of that dealership
- Financials for that dealership

Looking at it from just *one* dealership makes it all very easy, multiple apps within the main project (`Staff` app, `Inventory` app, etc.). I'm thinking that, even with multiple dealerships, I can still have that approach (separate apps for different areas).

But what I'm struggling with a bit is the URL patterns. Normally, the URLs might be setup like this:

```
top_level ("/"),
inventory ("/inventory/", include inventory_app(urls)),
financials ("/financials/", include financial_app(urls)),
```

The thing is, if I have multiple dealerships I want to view *all* the URLs, filtered based on that one dealership. So all URLs need to show their data, filtered on the one dealership.  Even things like creating a new staff member, it needs to be something like `/dealership_A/contacts/new/` or looking at financials would be `/dealership_A/financials/overview/`.

Then, to change dealerships, I'd go to the "dashboard" page (which would be to top level for the whole project) and select a different dealership. Now all URLs need to be filtered on *that* dealership. Something like `/dealership_B/contacts/new/` and `/dealership_B/financials/overview/`

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to design the project, and the URLs properly, given this project-wide filtering concept, where all URLs change, based on which dealership you're looking at. Is there some Django-esque way of doing this?

Comment: You should look into [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups). Using named groups, you can easily do something like you're referring to...For example, for financials, you could do something like: `url(r'^(?P<dealership>[a-zA-Z_-]+)/financials/$', views.financials)`

Comment: So then, in my `dealership/urls.py` that would mean I would have a *lot* or URLs and the `inventory/urls.py` and `financials/urls.py` would be largely empty. I would also have to keep track of which dealership I am viewing so that for every page and every link, the `dealership` PK would be available. 

I can't help but feel like there's got to be a better, more Django-esque way of doing this. Something like a `context_processor` or something.

Comment: Why do you think you would have a lot of URLs for dealerships? You should only have a couple of definitions if you're using named groups to pass the dealership name/slug/or PK to your views...The main `dealerships/` overview view would simply be a single `ListView` of all of your dealership instances.

Comment: Oh right, of course (misunderstanding your comment, sorry). However, with named groups, every URL and every `view` would need the `dealership` variable passed into it. Wouldn't that be a bit repetitive? I mean, I suppose that's the only way. For example, on another project, I have the whole site password protected. Instead of a decorator on each view, I have a `context_processor` checking if the user is logged in. That's the kind of *put it in one spot* idea I was hoping for. Setup the filtering for dealerships in *one spot* instead of sprinkled across all URLs and all views.